# System of equations with 3 variables

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

Consider the system of equation $x+y+z=2$ , $xy+yz+zx=1$ and $xyz= a$
Where $a$ is a fixed constant.

- 1. show that the system S is equivalent to ( $z^3-2z^2+z-a=0$ and $z \in [0,4/3]$)
- 2. find all values of a for which the system has at least one  solution

1. well for this question I proved that z z^3-2z^2+z-a=0 easily using that  z is a root to this polynomial since it os a solution to the system . Also i managed to prove that z>=0 , but didnt know how to prove z<=4/3
2. for this one , all i know is that a has to be positive

Answer (score 0):

$$x+y=2-z.$$
Thus, $$1=xy+z(2-z)\leq\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)^2+(2-z)z=\frac{(2-z)^2}{4}+(2-z)z,$$
which gives $$3z^2-4z\leq0$$ or
$$0\leq z\leq\frac{4}{3}.$$
The system has at least one real solution if $(x-y)^2(x-z)^2(y-z)^2\geq0.$

Let $x+y+z=3u,$ $xy+xz+yz=3v^2$ and $xyz=3v^2$.

Thus, $u=\frac{2}{3}$, $v^2=\frac{1}{3}$ and $w^3=a$.

Now, use the following identity.
$$\prod_{cyc}(x-y)^2=27(3u^2v^4-4v^6-4u^3w^3+6uv^2w^3-w^6).$$
We obtain:
$$3\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2-4\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^3-4\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3a+6\cdot\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\cdot a-a^2\geq0$$ or
$$4a-27a^2\geq0,$$ which gives $$0\leq a\leq\frac{4}{27}.$$
We can get the same result by analysis.

Indeed, $$(x^3-2x^2+x-a)'=3x^2-4x+1=(x-1)(3x-1),$$ which gives for $f(x)=x^3-2x^2+x$ that $x_{max}=\frac{1}{3}$ and $x_{min}=1$ and we need: $$f(1)\leq a\leq f\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$$ because we want that the equation $f(x)=a$ has three real roots.

Comment: Didnt understand how to find the value of a

Comment: @Ak04 I added something. See now.